# How to implement a make_rv function in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue, forward, forwarding-reference

I want to write a template which can turn lvalue/rvalue to rvalue using universal reference like std::forward
For rvalue, just forward it.
For lvalue, copy it.

it is used as below

```cpp
template<typename T>
void func(T&& arg) {
    f_take_rv(make_rv<T>(arg)); // f_take_rv takes right value only
}
```

Here is my implement

```cpp
template<typename T> // for lvalue
constexpr T make_rv(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& arg) {
    return arg;
}
template<typename T> // for rvalue
constexpr T&& make_rv(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& arg) {
    return static_cast<T&&>(arg);
}
```

However, it always goes to the lvalue one

I also tried std::enable_if to control its type deduction.

```cpp
template<typename T>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_reference<T>::value,
    typename std::remove_reference<T>::type
>::type make_rv(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& arg) { return arg; }

template<typename T>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_reference<T>::value,
    T
>::type&& make_rv(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& arg) {
    return static_cast<T&&>(arg);
}
```

But it failed for literal string, like "str": no matching function for call to 'make_rv<const char(&)[4]>(const char [4])'

Could you tell me how to implement it

gcc implement of std::forward for reference:

```cpp
template<typename _Tp>  // forwarding an lvalue
constexpr _Tp&&
forward(typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type& __t) noexcept {
    return static_cast<_Tp&&>(__t);
}
template<typename _Tp>  // forwarding an rvalue
constexpr _Tp&&
forward(typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&& __t) noexcept {
    return static_cast<_Tp&&>(__t);
}
```

Comment: `constexpr T make_rv()`, *However, it always goes to the lvalue one* - it is rvalue, a returned temporary value can't be lvalue.

Comment: yes, my purpose is to return a right value, for rvalue, forward it, for lvalue, copy and return it

Comment: `arg` is an lvalue, even when `T&&` is deduced to be rvalue reference. Rule of thumb: if it has a name, it's an lvalue. Look at the [documentation for `std::forward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward); note that the second overload is called only when the code does something like `std::forward<T>(f())`, forwarding the return value of a function.

Comment: The approach with `enable_if` should work, except that both overloads should take `type& arg`. You dispatch not on whether `arg` is an lvalue or rvalue, but on whether template parameter `T` is a reference type.

Answer (score 1):

I found a version works for me

```cpp
template<typename T> // for lvalue, copy it
constexpr typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_reference<T>::value,
    typename std::decay<T>::type
>::type make_rv(const T& arg) { return arg; }

template<typename T> // for rvalue, forward it
constexpr typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_reference<T>::value,
    T
>::type&& make_rv(T& arg) {
    return static_cast<T&&>(arg);
}
```

Comment: does it? https://godbolt.org/z/dxobjjhcs Maybe my test covers case which you don't use, but still, are you sure?

Comment: Is there any reason you're returning `T` for rvalues and not `T &&`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I am returning T for lvalue, T&& for rvalue

Comment: Hi @alagner, make_rv is used like std::forward. That is to say make_rv always take lvalue, and whether it originally was r/l value is presented in T with universal reference

Answer (score 1):

I would go probably the easiest route possible:

```cpp
template<typename T>
constexpr auto copy_l_forward_r(T&& arg)
    -> typename std::conditional<std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value && !std::is_array<T>::value,
        typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type, T&&>::type

{   
    return std::forward<T>(arg);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/WbbWPa5PE

The main question is what to do about references to C-style arrays. They can be returned "as-is" (thanks @JosephThomson for that comment), but they can also be decayed to a pointer.

To expand it a bit more: the whole confusion (as this is a recurring topic in one form or another) stems from the way type deduction works in C++.

Consider a function taking a forwarding/universal reference:
`template<typename T> void f(T&& f) {/*whatever*/}`
Imagine it's called with an integer literal:
`f(3);` What are types `T` and `arg` are going to be?
Hint: they're not going to be the same.
`T` is an `int`, `decltype(arg)` is is `int&&`.

Ok, so what about `int x = 4; f(x);`?
`T` is `int&`, `decltype(arg)` `int&`. Ok, so far so good.

Now the interesting part comes.
Consider the following code snippet:

```cpp
static int i = 3;
int& lvint() { return i; }
int&& rvint() {return std::move(i);}
```

What are the types inside f going to be?
`f(lvint());`
Now, both `T` and `decltype(arg)` are `int&`.
Still, nice, easy and predictable.

Now take:
`f(rvint());` and this is where the plot thickens.
`decltype(arg)` is `int&&`, but `T` is `int`. Not a reference.

I cannot point my finger at the exact chapter in the standard that is responsible for this, the closest one I can think of is this:

> A forwarding reference is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter that does not represent a template parameter of a class template (during class template argument deduction ([over.match.class.deduct])).
> If P is a forwarding reference and the argument is an lvalue, the type “lvalue reference to A” is used in place of A for type deduction.
> https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call

My personal rule of thumb (but just a personal opinion, so feel free to disagree) is this: it is more predictable to operate on the `decltype(arg)` rather than T when fiddling with perfect forwarding. Or, when operating on T: keep in mind that T can be a non-reference type unless it's a lvalue one.

And some examples to illustrate all the above:
https://godbolt.org/z/dzzqdrM8T

Comment: Your implementation fails for const lvalues and array references.

Comment: @JosephThomson how does it fail for `const T&`? `static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(copy_l_forward_r(clvint())), int>, "");` seems fine, can you show the exact case?

Comment: Sorry, the function itself won't fail, but it will return `const T` when you pass it `const T&`, which will fail to bind to `T&&`. Changing `std::remove_reference_t<T>` to `std::remove_cvref_t<T>` should fix it (though neither is C++11 compatible).

Comment: And I think the array reference incompatibility can be fixed by changing `std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T>` to `std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T> && !std::is_array_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>`.

Comment: @JosephThomson OK I see now. But interestingly enough, it returns `int` (non-const) for `const int&` argument, so there's probably sth more at play that we're missing.

Comment: @JosephThomson fixed. I will update the examples with proper tests later. Turns out that using primitive types led me astray. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, nothing fancy is required:

```cpp
template <typename T>
typename std::remove_const<T>::type make_rv(T& t)
{
    return t;
}

template <typename T>
T&& make_rv(T&& t)
{
    return std::forward<T>(t);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Joseph Thomson,  In my use case, make_rv is used like std::forward. That is to say make_rv always take lvalue, and whether it originally was r/l value is presented in T with universal reference